# Numerically stable method for sampling from truncated normal distribution

Tags: statistics, algorithms, computer-science

I am [implementing](https://github.com/TheAeryan/stable-truncated-gaussian) a truncated normal (gaussian) distribution N(x | μ, σ, a, b) in Python that is both **differentiable** with respect to its parameters and **numerically stable** when μ is outside the interval [a, b].

I have been able to implement numerically stable methods for calculating the mean, variance and log-probability. Next, I need to implement a method for **sampling** from the distribution. This [Stack Exchange post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/490877/what-is-the-ppf-of-the-truncated-normal-distribution) proposes the following method: $$ x = \Phi^{-1}(\Phi(\alpha) + U \cdot (\Phi(\beta)-\Phi(\alpha))\sigma + \mu $$

Thanks to the *reparameterization trick*, this expression is differentiable with respect to the distribution parameters. Nonetheless, it results numerically unstable when the expression inside $\Phi^{-1}$ gets very close to either -1 or 1.

Therefore, my question is the following: **Is there a method for sampling from a truncated normal distribution that is both stable and differentiable?**

Comment: why isn't reparanerization stable? and what do you mean by differential sampling?

Comment: Presumably you intended "the expression inside $\Phi^{-1}$ gets very close to either $\mathbf 0$ or $1$."  Using R, you can handle these extreme cases in the `qnorm( )` function using the `log.p` and `lower.tail` parameters

Comment: @user619894 The expression above is not stable because when the expression inside $\Phi^{-1}$ gets very close to either 0 or 1, a very small approximation error will have huge impacts in the output of $\Phi^{-1}$. By differential sampling, I mean being able to calculate error gradients through the sampling process, as the [rsample](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/distributions.html) function in Pytorch.

Comment: @Henry Isn't it between -1 and 1? Here's the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function#Inverse_functions) link. I've taken a look at the `log.p` and `lower.tail` options in R and I'm not entirely sure how I can apply that to my problem (e.g., calculate log-probs in order to make it stable?)

Comment: $\mathbb P(X \le x)=\Phi(x)$ is a probability so between $0$ and $1$, and so $\Phi^{-1}(p)$ only considers $p$ between $0$ and $1$.   If you try $\Phi^{-1}(-\frac12)$ then you will get an error

Comment: You can use asymptotic expansion for the tails, notice that the normalization to 1 in the range $[a,b]$ means that if you are far enough from the mean, the Gaussian decays roughly exponentially since $e^{-(x_0+\Delta)^2}\sim e^{-x_0^2}e^{-2x_0 \Delta}$

Comment: @user619894 Thank you very much for your answer. What do you mean by *normalization to 1 in the range $[a,b]$*? Sorry for the question, I'm actually not a statistician

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but if you mean for all samples to be in the interval, then the probablilty to fall inside the interval must be 1. This means that the truncated Gaussian must be made to have an integral  of 1 in the range, so the "usual"  Gaussian needs to be scaled.

Comment: So, by *normalization to 1 in the range  $[a,b]$* you mean *truncating a gaussian distribution in the interval $[a,b]$*, right? Then, if I understood correctly, you propose two different methods for sampling. 1), if $\mu$ is *close* to the interval $[a,b]$, we can simply use the formula I wrote in my post, since it is numerically stable. 2), if $\mu$ is *very far* from $[a,b]$, approximate the truncated gaussian with another distribution (you talked about *asymptotic expansion*) from which we can sample in a numerically stable manner. Am I right?

Comment: @Henry Sorry, you are right. I messed up $\Phi^{-1}$ and the inverse cdf function.

Answer (score 1):

Let me propose a quick and dirty method:

The probability to see $x\in[\alpha,\beta]$ is
$P(x)={1\over Z}e^{{-x^2}\over2}$ where $Z$ is a normalization factor:
$$Z=\int_\alpha^\beta e^{{-x^2}\over2}dx$$.
In you case $\alpha,\beta\gg 1$, so we nay write $x=\alpha+y$ and for $y\in[0,\beta-\alpha]$
$$P(y)={1\over Z}e^{{-(\alpha+y)^2}\over2}={1\over Z}e^{{-\alpha^2-2\alpha y-y^2}\over2}$$.
A long as $\alpha\gg\beta-\alpha$, we can ignore the $y^2$ term in the exponent, since the $2\alpha y$ term is always much bigger. Thus we have
$$P(y)={1\over W}e^{-\alpha y}$$ where I wrote $W$ to take into account the various normalizations, but we can compute it explictly:

Since $1=\int_0^{\beta-\alpha} P(y)dy$ we must have $W=\int_0^{\beta-\alpha} e^{-\alpha y}dy={1-e^{-(\beta-\alpha)\alpha}\over \alpha}\approx {1\over \alpha}$, again since $(\beta-\alpha)\alpha\gg 1$ so that the term is exponentially small.

We are left with generating random exponential numbers.
Generating exponential random numbers via reparametrization is [a classical technique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution#Random_variate_generation).

To conclude:

1. when $\alpha,\beta\gg1$ the Gaussian looks like an exponential in the vicinity of $\alpha$.
2. The exponential decays so fast, that the chance of ever selecting a number near $\beta$ is negligible. If you still need it, you can probably get away with correcting the normalization factor, with no need to add the $y^2$ term in the exponential.
3. exponential random variates can be generated via reparametrization.
4. The crossover regime, where one can either use the full blown $\Phi^{-1}$ reparametrization *or* the exponential approximation may need some smoothing to interpolate.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! And sorry for the late reply, I've been quite busy lately. I tried a similar approach to yours, basically modelling the truncated gaussian (TN) as an exponential distribution whenever $\alpha \le 4$. I used the following exp dist: $p_a*e^{-p_a*y}$, where $p_a$ is the probability assigned by the TN to $x=a$. This implementation is available at this [github repo](https://github.com/TheAeryan/stable-truncated-gaussian). It works fine in many cases but, when $a$ is close to $b$, it provides a bad approximation. What would you suggest to solve this issue?

Comment: Examples of how my `icdf` implementation fails when compared to the "real" icdf (computed using the `scipy` library) can be found in this [folder](https://github.com/TheAeryan/stable-truncated-gaussian/tree/main/images_icdf_comparison). My approximation of the tail of a TN using an exp distribution sometimes returns values outside $[a,b]$ (equiv., icdf outside $[0,1]$), so I clip the output to the $[a,b]$ range.

Comment: I am not sure how you calculated $p_a$, is it the same as my $\alpha$? If your problem is generating a *truncated* exponential distribution then you can probably use a uniform distribution in the range $[\epsilon,1]$ and take the -log.

Comment: In my implementation, $p_a \neq \alpha$ but $p_a \neq N(x=a|\mu,\sigma,a,b)$ (in other words, the probability the truncated gaussian assigns to $a$ instead of $a$ itself). I tried using $\lambda=\alpha$ as you suggested, but the approximation would be worse. And yes, I think my problem is generating a truncated exponential distribution (I think that's why I need to clip the `icdf` between 0 and 1). What do you mean by the "use a uniform distribution ... and take the -log"?

Comment: To answer the second question, I mean that you can generate a truncated exponential distribution using the inverse transform technique. Say you want to generate a truncated exponential with range $[0, r]$ . Generate a uniform variate $U$ in the range  $[e^{-r},1]$ and take $-\log(U)$.

Comment: As for your first, I don't understand it. In my opinion, the behavior of the tail of a Gaussian $e^{-x^2\over 2}$ for $x=\alpha+y 1$ with $\alpha\gg1$ and $y\ll\alpha$ is like $e^{-\alpha y}$ (up to normalizations).

Comment: If I understood your comment correctly, you suggest to approximate a Gaussian as an Exponential distribution when $\alpha \gg 1$. An exponential distribution is of the form $\lambda*e^{-\lambda y}$ (where $x=\alpha+y$ in my case) so we need to find a value for $\lambda$. I tried using $\lambda=\alpha$ but that results in a bad approximation. $\lambda=p_a$ works better. Still, the issue is that $\lambda*e^{-\lambda y}$ is untruncated, so I need to obtain the formula for a *truncated* exponential in the range $[\alpha,\beta]$. Then, I need to obtain its *icdf* (ppf) function.

Comment: I would like to add that I need this exponential-based approximation of the tail of a gaussian to work for both *large* intervals (i.e., when $\beta \gg \alpha$) and *small* intervals (i.e., when $\beta \sim \alpha$). The only assumption I can make is that $\alpha \gg 1$ (right now, I use this approximation whenever $\alpha > 3$).

Comment: the truncation shoudnt affect the exponential decay *rate*, only the normalization and the behavior beyond the truncation.

Comment: I followed your previous comment and now I got it right. Basically, I use the `icdf` of an exponential $\lambda*e^{-\lambda*y}$, where $\lambda=N(x=a|\mu,\sigma,a,b)$ (i.e., $\lambda=p_a$). In order to truncate this distribution, I follow your advice and scale the percentile from $p \in [0,1]$ to $p \in [0, p_{\gamma}]$, where $\gamma=\beta-\alpha$ and $p_{\gamma}=1-e^{-\gamma \lambda}$. This approximation for `icdf` works much better than my previous one, although it needs some improvement for the cases where $\alpha \sim \beta$.

Comment: If you agree on the followed approach, do you think you could edit your posted answer with the additional details so that I can accept it? If not, I will post the answer on my own :)

Comment: Unfortunately I can't reconcile your exponent with mine. You are of course free to post your own answer.